# Bayes' Theorem and Science

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, bayesian

1. More than one hypothesis may fit the data (hypotheses generation is the stock-in-trade of science)
2. Choosing a scientific hypothesis is *not* about *truth*. People have gone on record that *inter alia* it's about *simplicity* (Occam's razor)

Ergo,

3. Scientific hypotheses are *not* truths. They're best thought of as *models* that *fit* with *observation*.

---

Bayes' theorem, in the context of science, can be summed up as P(H/E) which, translated into English, means *The probability that a hypothesis H is **true**, given the *evidence* E*.

---

To cut to the chase, Bayes' theorem is a probabilistic calculation of **truth** of a scientific hypothesis, but scientific hypotheses are not about **truth** (*vide supra*).

---

How do we explain this *incongruence*, **IF** it is one?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141921/discussion-on-question-by-agent-smith-bayes-theorem-and-science).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by true. Scientific theories such as relativity and quantum mechanics are models of reality. An accepted meaning of 'true' is 'in accord with facts or reality'. Therefore, one might refer to scientific theories as being true if they model reality to an acceptable extent. Your 'incongruity' seems to arise only because you use the words true and truth in different ways.

Comment: An interesting obaervation. You, I believe, hit the bullseye mon ami. However, you do admit that there are two very different meanings of *truth* at play here. What about the fact that all other contender hypotheses are also "in accord" with *the facts*?

Comment: @AgentSmith I think we should give up on using the word "true". I don't think science really needs it anyway. Science provides "models that fit with observation", as you say. That's enough. It's a mistake to drag science into making it say that some things are "true", except, as Marco says, in the sense that they are "truthful" to observation as far as we know. Again, that's enough. I really think we should not try to find "truth" or use the word "truth".

Comment: Agreed, but then *what's the meaning* of P(H/E) where H is a *scientific hypothesis* and E is *evidence* for that hypothesis? You made a good suggestion - interpret *true* as being "in accord with the facts" but then, as I brought to yer attention, *all* hypotheses (there's always more than one) are "in accord with the facts".

Comment: @AgentSmith in that sense of the word true, there are degrees of truth. We used to consider Newton's law of gravitation to be correct until Einstein came up with a truer model.

Comment: I had the same idea, but how does 90% true differ from 100% true in terms of *truth*?

Comment: @AgentSmith I'm not sure truth may be meaningfully quantified in quite the way you are imagining.

Comment: @MarcoOcram,  I'm not saying H is 90% true, I'm saying H is 90% likely to be true.

Comment: @AgentSmith but even then, do you mean 90% likely to be 100% true?  The probability can be quantified, but the extent to which something is true may be harder to quantify.

Comment: A proposition is true/false i.e. it is either 100% true or 100% false; there's no *grey zone* between true and false unless you're using some version of *fuzzy logic* which I've only heard of but never applied.

Comment: @AgentSmith you are talking at cross purposes again, by assuming H is a logical proposition which must be true or false, whereas we had been talking of H as a scientific hypothesis which need not be true or false in a binary sense.

Comment: @MarcoOcram, the phraseology I've employed here is taken verbatim from a Wikipedia article on Bayes' theorem. The mathematical expression P(H/E) reads **the probability that hypothesis H is *true* given the evidence E**. This is standard interpretation, not my personal point of view. Hence the question. A book on logic contains the exact same interpretation of P(H/E). If you think a hypothesis needn't be true or false in binary sense then explain to me the meaning of Einstein's *theory* (which was once a hypothesis) is 90% true.

Comment: @AgentSmith I can't because it is not meaningful to do so.

Comment: @MarcoOcram, says "I have a **PhD** in **quantum theory**." You're kidding, right?

Comment: @AgentSmith, "how does 90% true differ from 100% true in terms of truth?" Statistically this means out of all observed data, the hypothesis fits 100%/90%/50% of the data. Adding more data to the dataset gives more opportunities for a given hypothesis to establish that it does not fit all the data. A "True" hypothesis will fit 100% of the data no matter the size of the data set. Half-true statements fit half the data. Untrue (false) hypotheses fit none or almost no data. Also **quantum theory** is not statistics. I highly recommend Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics to learn the basics

Comment: @AgentSmith, In general scientific hypotheses make specific claims about specific phenomena and make measurable claims about outcomes and results of experiments. Non-scientific hypotheses either don't make specific claims, don't make measurable claims, or cannot be applied to experiment.

Comment: @Gerald, gracias. So if a hypothesis H is said to be  x% true, it means it explains/fits x% of the observations? What *true* is in Bayes' theorem is not the same *true* in *it is **true** that the Eiffel tower is in Paris, France*. If H accords with all the observations, it seems, H is true in the same sense as *the Eiffel tower is in Paris, France*.

Comment: @AgentSmith, the broader and more accurate explanations require you to read and understand a statistics textbook. "Truth" is context dependent. For example the concept of a data fit is much broader and more technical than I explained.

Comment: @Gerald, gracias for the guidance. At my level of understanding, a given set of observation squares with multiple hypotheses H1, H2, H3, ..., Hn. Now to make a choice. I hear that *Occam's razor* is a handy tool. In short, I'd need to use a combo - Bayes' theorem + the *novacula occami*.

Comment: Occam's razor is mostly an aesthetic tool for preferring one hypothesis over another when both fit the data equally. Atoms and quantum particles are more preferable than fairies and demons because it is simpler. It is entirely possible to arbitrarily construct hypotheses of fairies and demons that make the same predictions. If you do, then phenologically they are identical explanations where you have just decided to call electrons demons and protons fairies. If the alternative offers identical predictions, but requires more complicated explanations, then Occam's razor says to exclude it.

Comment: That is merely meant to be explanatory. Most hypotheses which feature entities called "non-physical" or the like often imply that it should be possible to affect the world in very specific ways that are not generally observed. In laboratory conditions most of these explanations offer no additional explanation other than "I don't know" or "that's not how my hypothesis explains these observations". Souls definitely exist until you try to weigh them. Demons definitely exist until antibiotics and medicine offer better explanations.

Comment: phenomenologically*

Answer (score 1):

I would put pressure on your second assumption.
As there many reasons of way and how to choose one scientific hypotheses out of the many that are possible, and parsimony is a leading reason, but for sure no the only one.

Also, you if have problems with the definition of truth, you should use bayes the following way:
"The probability that a hypothesis H **fits the data better than others**, given the evidence E."

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that's an acceptable answer?